# Is there a way to integrate a packaged game (Unreal Engine 4) apk into an application that is developed using React-Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, integration, unreal-engine4

We are a video game developing comapny that uses Unreal Engine 4 to develop games.
We have a client who has an application under development for both Android and the iOS on their own (we did are not the ones developing it for them). They are developing their application using React-Native.

We would like to develop a game for them using Unreal Engine 4. But, we would like it to be integrated into their application.

Is there a way to integrate a packaged game (Unreal Engine 4) apk into an application that is developed using React-Native?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the [React-UMG](https://github.com/ncsoft/React-UMG) module to a similar approach.

It's something related to unreal engine itself, as said [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/UMG/index.html)

And, you can use [Unreal.js](https://github.com/ncsoft/Unreal.js) to something like this

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I will look into and come back with feedback. In general, how will the projects intersect?

Comment: I dont know how far can you go, even how big is your game, but as said on the unreal.js [readme](https://github.com/ncsoft/Unreal.js/blob/master/README.md) , looks like you can build a game using their module to javascript. Of course it will need some modifications to serve your necessities

Comment: [here's](https://github.com/ncsoft/Unreal.js/tree/master/Examples/Content/Scripts/2048) their 2048 game using Unreal.js

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. It seems that going with a Javascript based game engine such as Phaser is the better choice for us.

Answer (score 2):

Unreal.js and Unreal-UMG seems the best fit for your needs. I had written Unreal.js in ncsoft and it is being maintained by my former colleagues on ncsoft.

Unreal-UMG lets you write UI logic with React and the rendering is being delivered by Unreal slate subsystem (All the features of UE are accessible).

If you are wondering about producing and releasing games built on unreal.js to the real market, it might be worth to watch this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CW6j7twaUCE) (although the vid is dubbed in Korean)

Answer (score 0):

im not 100% sure but i think you can use react native unity view, a third party library which provide a way to render 3D scenes in React Native apps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).